# Losing Aria/accessibility when converting from HTML to PDF

Tags: pdf, accessibility, abcpdf

I am using ABCpdf to generate a collection of PDFs from HTML markup, and am struggling with making it fully accessible.

The HTML pages include several graphs which are created by CSS, and which are completely ignored by the screenreader.

I have tried using aria-label to give a written explanation of the graphs, but it is lost in the conversion. I have tried configuring the Gecko engine within ABCpdf in numerous ways, including scaling back security options, altering markup options, and adding special tags to explicitly include an element. The PDF is tagged and is rated as fully accessible by our evaluation program.

I haven't been able to find a way to include "hidden" text in the PDF for the purpose of screenreaders. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Due to security concerns, I am unable to display the actual data behind the graphs. Manual steps are also not an option due to the sheer number of generated PDFs, and a short timeline.

Answer (score 0):

HTML-to-PDF conversion utilities are usually pretty basic and typically don't handle complex CSS very well at all. You may be better off taking a screen capture and then using alt-text to describe the intent of the graph. Sometimes the simplest approach is the most reliable.

Another way of approaching the issue would be to present the complete data set to users via a data table. That way, they can "see" everything contained in the graph, and it won't matter if the graph itself is inaccessible. If placing a giant data table in the middle of your document doesn't fit with your formatting, you can also include the data set in an appendix with a note or hyperlink in the text directing readers where they can go to access the entirety of information.

Comment: These are good ideas. I didn't mention that 1) security concerns mean we can't display the actual data and 2) the sheer number of dynamically generated PDFs mean that manual steps are out of the question. I appreciate the answer!